# Automatically include repo owner's name when cloning

Tags: git

I clone repos from many different sources. Sometimes it can be confusing who was the source of one of these repos that all sit in my git folder. To fix this I have started manually creating a subfolder with the repo owner's name and then cloning in that subfolder. Is there a way to do this automatically? To have git read the owners name and then clone into /?

Comment: "*[...] these repos that all sit in my git folder.*" Do you have repos nested within another?

Comment: `git clone` takes a URI and a destination folder as arguments. Under the condition that you can extract the owner's name from the URI (you can with GitHub URIs, for instance), you can write a wrapper around `git clone` that would do what you want. See [Ry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50750718/2541573) for a possible implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git clone` takes an optional second argument for a destination:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo username-repo
```

which you could automate with a shell script for some recognizable providers, something like:

```
github-clone() {
    local dest="$(printf %s "$1" | sed -n 's#^.*[/:]\([[:alnum:]-]\+\)/\([[:alnum:]-]\+\)\(\.git\)\?$#\1-\2#p')"
    if [[ -z "$dest" ]]; then
        git clone "$1"
    else
        git clone "$1" "$dest"
    fi
}
```

```
$ github-clone https://github.com/username/repo
Cloning into 'username-repo'...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this handcrafted Bash alias `clone` (see below) in the following way:

```
$ clone https://github.com/coq/coq.git ~/git/
+ git clone https://github.com/coq/coq.git /home/user/git/coq/coq
Cloning into '/home/user/git/coq/coq'...

$ clone git@github.com:coq/coq.git .
+ git clone git@github.com:coq/coq.git ./coq/coq
Cloning into './coq/coq'...
```

It works with both HTTPS and SSH GitHub repos:

```
alias clone='f(){ [[ $# -ne 2 ]] && { echo "\$ clone git@github.com:user/repo.git ."; return 1; } || ( tmp="${1##*github.com?}"; set -x; git clone "$1" "${2%/}/${tmp%.git}" ) }; f'
```

But if you don't want to automatically prepend the username of the GitHub repo and want at the same time to generalize to other Git URLs that are not GitHub-related, you can just replace `tmp="${1##*github.com?}"` with `tmp="${1##*/}"`:

```
alias clone='f(){ [[ $# -ne 2 ]] && { echo "\$ clone git@github.com:user/repo.git ."; return 1; } || ( tmp="${1##*/}"; set -x; git clone "$1" "${2%/}/${tmp%.git}" ) }; f'
```

E.g.:

```
$ clone https://github.com/coq/coq.git ~/git/other-user
+ git clone https://github.com/coq/coq.git /home/user/git/other-user/coq
Cloning into '/home/user/git/other-user/coq'...
```